# resteasy client in a multithreaded java server environment

Tags: multithreading, weblogic, resteasy, java-5

All,

I have implemented resteasy client in a java code base which is deployed to weblogic server (9.x) version . Am using resteasy jar versions 1.2 which are compatible with JDK 1.5.

This deployable is deployed to a clustered weblogic instances where multithreading is possible.

Can some one let me know whether REST EASY 1.2 version is thread safe ? Do i need to add anything else to the below sample implementation code ? (Sample code below)

Please share your thoughts.

```
                String uri ="http://abc:8080"
                ClientRequestFactory crf = new ClientRequestFactory(UriBuilder.fromUri(uri).build());
                ClientRequest request = crf.createRelativeRequest("/getDetails?q=1");

                request.accept("application/xml");
                ClientResponse<Output> response = null;
                ClientResponse responseString = null;
                Output ou = null;

                try {

                    response = request.get();
                    ou= response.getEntity();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: No it is not thread safe by default. You will need to create a client similar to what is being done at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508480/resteasy-client-proxy-overhead

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp thanks for the link. I need to use  MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(connectionManager); ClientExecutor clientExecutor = new ApacheHttpClientExecutor(httpClient);
 ClientRequestFactory fac = new ClientRequestFactory(clientExecutor,uri);

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp                                                   in the code . I assume i need to use                                     response.releaseConnection(); statement  - is that enough ? what about httpclient settings - how to close it