# Is ResteasyClient threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, resteasy

I want to avoid creating a new `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient 3.0.9`when my `Service` method gets called; so I want to set it as member variable in the `Service` class. Therefore, I'd want to know if `ResteasyClient` **threadsafe**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. By default, the ResteasyClient is not thread safe because of its underlying HTTP dependencies. [RESTEasy Client Proxy Overhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508480/resteasy-client-proxy-overhead) has a way to create a client in a threadsafe way.

Comment: So if I use `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` to create the `HttpClient`, then it should be thread safe?