# What scope should be used for ResteasyClient?

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus, resteasy

I am a bit confused about the proper scope of `ResteasyClient` in `Quarkus`. Based on the [Quarkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#create-the-configuration), the default scope for `ResteasyClient` is `@Dependent` which is bound to the bean injecting it, as in [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#bean-scope-available) explain. What I understand about it is that, if I inject an un-scoped `ResteasyClient` within an `@ApplicationScope` class, it will be created once. On the other hand, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992066/4243558), `ResteasyClient` is not thread safe.

Now my questions are, First of all, is it right to inject a `ResteasyClient` with its default scope(`@Dependent`) to a class with `@ApplicationScope`?

And Second, is there any advices and best practices about `ResteasyClient` scoping?

Comment: From what I know you should have 1 client per app. And this client has a pool of connections, so that each request uses its own connection, which is threadsafe.